# FTP explicit TLS connection Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

Goodmorning everyone, I'm trying to connect with python to the ip address of my explicit FTP server on TLS ...

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

def Ftp_Transfer():
      
    ftps = FTP_TLS('ftp://username@IP:PORT')
    ftps.login(user='username', passwd='pass')
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Lavori\Organizzazione\LOG_Windows.p
y", line 13, in Ftp_Transfer
    ftps = FTP_TLS('ftp://username@IP:PORT')
  File "C:\Users\Utente\Anaconda3\lib\ftplib.py", line 745, in __init__
    FTP.__init__(self, host, user, passwd, acct, timeout, source_address)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\Anaconda3\lib\ftplib.py", line 117, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\Anaconda3\lib\ftplib.py", line 152, in connect
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 707, in create_connection

    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Utente\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

(I bring up FileZilla because that is the only server we consistantly have problems with)

I do know that FTP_TLS does not support FileZilla servers running on modern configurations - There has been work to hack the FTP_TLS implementation, but even that doesn't work on 2020 FileZilla default configs.

We ended up running lftp from the commant-line, through Python. Please note this is a HORRIBLE idea (security vulnerability) if any input comes from an un-trusted user.

Example of our implementation below.
Works for Implicit FTP over TLS:

```
import os
# add `;set xfer:clobber yes` to -e arguments to enable file overwrite
os.system('lftp -u %(username)s,%(password)s -e "set ssl:verify-certificate no;get %(remote_filename)s -o %(local_filename)s;exit" ftps://%(host)s' % {
        'username': USERNAME,
        'password': PASSWORD,
        'host': HOST,
        'remote_filename': '/filename-to-download.txt',
        'local_filename': '/path/to/filename.txt',
    }
)
```

If you don't have lftp installed, on Ubuntu you can simply run:

```
apt install lftp
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're reporting in the last line of the trace tells the tale:

> socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed

This error means the host (ftp server) had a resolution problem. Presuming that you've verified that the host is up and reachable via the IP or hostname you specified, this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ftplib import FTP_TLS

def Ftp_Transfer():      
    ftps = FTP_TLS('127.0.0.1') # replace with your host name or IP
    ftps.login(user='username', passwd='xxxxxx')

Ftp_Transfer()
```

This is the description of Error 11003 from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa924071(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):
[image]